# iOS Reload Table Methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tab bar, the first view requires a login alertview and that works fine. When I switch to the next tab, I have a table view.

i am fetching data from online using JSON in a method which I call from the viewDidLoad method in a table view controller along with another login procedure. I want two sections and the data in each section depends on one of the properties I get from parsing the data.

The problem is that by the time the data is parsed, the table view methods would already be finished so I get 0 section and 0 rows and no data displaying. 
So my question is, is there a way to just reload the no of sections method, no of rows method and the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. If i reload the entire table view, I get infinite alertviews asking for login :/

EDIT:

```
     #import "BooksViewController.h"
     #import "Me.h"
     #import "SBJson.h"

     @interface BooksViewController ()

     @end

     @implementation BooksViewController

     @synthesize name = _name;
     @synthesize ID = _id;
     @synthesize extended = _extended;
     @synthesize returned = _returned;
     @synthesize Date = _date;

     -(void) dealloc
     {
         self.name = nil;
         self.ID = nil;
         self.extended = nil;
         self.returned = nil;
         [super dealloc];
     }

     - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
     {
         self = [super initWithStyle:style];
         if (self) {

             BooksBorrowed = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             BorrowedDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             BorrowedIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             BorrowedExtensions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             BorrowedReturns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

             /*message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login with your User                            ID and Password"
              message:nil
              delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
              otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

              [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];*/
             //book = [[BooksViewController alloc]init];
             me = [[Me alloc]init];
         }
         return self;
     }

     - (void)MyBooks
     {
NSString *authFormatString =
@"http://localhost:8888/Jineel_lib/bookBorrowed.php?uid=%d";

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, 1];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

response1 = [contents JSONValue];
if(contents)
{
    NSLog(@"contents : %@",contents);
    BookName = [[NSString alloc]init];
    DateBorrowed = [[NSString alloc]init];
    BookID = [[NSString alloc]init];
    BookExtended = [[NSString alloc]init];
    BookReturned = [[NSString alloc]init];

    BookName = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookName"];
    BookID = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookID"];
    DateBorrowed = [response1 valueForKey:@"DateBorrowed"];
    BookExtended = [response1 valueForKey:@"Extended"];
    BookReturned = [response1 valueForKey:@"Returned"];

    [BooksBorrowed addObject:BookName];
    [BorrowedDates addObject:DateBorrowed];
    [BorrowedIDs addObject:BookID];
    [BorrowedReturns addObject:BookReturned];
    [BorrowedExtensions addObject:BookExtended];

    NSLog(@"Arrays are : %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", BooksBorrowed, BorrowedDates, BorrowedIDs, BorrowedReturns, BorrowedExtensions);
         }
     }


     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad];

         // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
         // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

         // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar          for this view controller.
         // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
         [self MyBooks];
     }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
[sup         er didReceiveMemoryWarning];
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

     #pragma mark - Table view data source

     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
         // Return the number of sections.
         return 1;
     }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(         (NSInteger)section
     {
         // Return the number of rows in the section.
         NSLog(@"rows %d", [BooksBorrowed count]);
         return [BooksBorrowed count];
     }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
         }

                  bookName = BooksBorrowed[0];

                  cell.textLabel.text = bookName;
                  return cell;
     }

     @end
```

Comment: This has **absolutely nothing** to do with Xcode at all.

Comment: what about wait till all data is parsed and then reload?

Comment: sincerely i do not understand what your problem is. If you call the reloadData method of the UITableView you will get all the delegate methods called (n. of section, n. of rows for section and cellForRowAtIndexPath). And no method (that you don't directly call from inside these methods) of the view /view controller that owns the table view will be called

Comment: @AntonioE. that is the problem :/, I am parsing something and according to the data i have parsed I want to set up my table view but my table view loads before the parsing

Comment: Why are you telling the run loop to run? You should really read some basic iOS networking tutorials and try to follow those - the WWDC videos and sample code probably are good places to start. Also stop naming everything with capital letters, it makes it harder to read. If you adopt the conventions of the platform you're developing for you'll find others will understand your code better and help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching the data should be done on a background thread, so that the UI is not blocked. After the data is fetched, the table view data source is updated and the table view reloaded. This must be done on the main thread.

The following code should demonstrate the idea:

```
- (void)updateMyBooks
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Fetch data on a background thread:
        NSURL *url = ...;
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        if (contents) {
            NSMutableArray *newBooksBorrowed = [NSMutableArray array];

            // ... Parse JSON response and add objects to newBooksBorrowed ...

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update data source array and reload table view.
                BooksBorrowed = newBooksBorrowed;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. thanks a lot... Where do I call this method? ViewDidLoad or?

Comment: hey, when I put this to set up my table, it crashes, can you tell me where I am going wrong? cell.textLabel.text = [BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @user2176687: You can call this in viewDidLoad. Do you have any error messages for the crash?

Comment: No it simply crashes, leaves nothing in the log

Comment: @user2176687: Then it is difficult to help. You should check the value and class of `BooksBorrowed` and of `[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:0]` in the debugger.

Comment: it comes out fine in the debugger... Please refer to my question on this matter for greater detail :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522672/xcode-table-view-cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to go with.

Wait till parse in end in your current  thread.

```
-(void)aFunc {
    //your job A
    while (A is not finished) {
        // If A job is finished, a flag should be set. and the flag can be a exit condition of this while loop
        // This executes another run loop.
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

[yourTable reloadData];
}
```

Or load only specific section.

```
– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
– reloadSectionIndexTitles
```

EDIT:

Another way is by [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), by using Serial Queue. `dispatch_sync()`, the block is enqueued and the function will not return until the block is executed.

Comment: i want to wait until all the data is parsed and then reload it. That is what I had in mind. How do I call specific methods of the tableview delegate?[self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:YES]?

Comment: I have tried [self.tableview reloaddata] but when I do it, it also calls the the view did load method and then I end up with inifinite loops of the login alertview :/

Comment: I guess you are parsing inside the delegate, move it out.

Comment: i am getting an error in this code: cell.textLabel.text = bookName;

Comment: I am parsing it in a seperate method and I call the method in viewDidLoad

Comment: @user2176687: As  Antonio E. said above: There is **no reason** why `reloadData` should call `viewDidLoad`! If you show your code it would be easier to find the proper solution to your problem.

Comment: show your full code in your question by writing EDIT:

Comment: I have edited my entire class m file

Comment: This code will either block the main thread waiting or call UI updates on a background thread, either of which is wrong.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: What should be used? GCD?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya that's probably the most straightforward approach.

Comment: so how exactly do I solve this problem? :/

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I update the answer, any suggestions.