# XCode, table view cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I know there is a simple solution to this but I can't seem to be able to tell :/

```
cell.textLabel.text = [BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:0];
```

I have that in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, bookName is a string.
It crashes and leaves no error in log. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

bookName is a string that i get from JSON Parsing and has content.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog(@"Book Name is %@", BooksBorrowed[0]);
    cell.textLabel.text = [BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:0];

    return cell;
  }
```

This is how I get the BooksBorrowed array:

```
 - (void)updateMyBooks
  {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Fetch data on a background thread:
        NSString *authFormatString =
        @"http://localhost:8888/Jineel_lib/bookBorrowed.php?uid=%d";

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, 1];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        response1 = [contents JSONValue];

        if (contents) {
          NSMutableArray *newBooksBorrowed = [NSMutableArray array];

          // ... Parse JSON response and add objects to newBooksBorrowed ...
          BookName = [[NSString alloc]init];
          DateBorrowed = [[NSString alloc]init];
          BookID = [[NSString alloc]init];
          BookExtended = [[NSString alloc]init];
          BookReturned = [[NSString alloc]init];

          BookName = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookName"];
          BookID = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookID"];
          DateBorrowed = [response1 valueForKey:@"DateBorrowed"];
          BookExtended = [response1 valueForKey:@"Extended"];
          BookReturned = [response1 valueForKey:@"Returned"];
          NSLog(@"Book Name is %@", BookName);

          [newBooksBorrowed addObject:BookName];

          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // Update data source array and reload table view.
          BooksBorrowed = newBooksBorrowed;
          [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
});
```

}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this line of code. Try putting in all the code from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: ...and how you create/store bookName, and whether you use ARC or not

Comment: please refer to the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my questions was :

I had to change the part where I add my data into the table to :

```
 NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This is because a table view tends to not take things of element 0. Also I took out newBooksBorrowed and it works with just the BooksBorrowed array. :) Thank you everyone for helping me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure bookName is a valid NSString?  I would break at that line of code and type

```
po bookName
```

in the debugger to see if what you are assigning to `bookName` is in fact a valid NSString.

Oh, and make sure you returning a valid UITableViewCell at the end of that method, or else it is guaranteed your code will break.

Comment: are you on the latest Xcode version and are you using ARC?  Im assuming you are not because `autorelease` wont compile

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code **BooksBorrowed = newBooksBorrowed;** with this in your function

```
BooksBorrowed = [[NSString alloc] initWithArray:newBooksBorrowed];
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding..
Thanks.

Comment: please post your tableview methods.. and have u checked that array is filled with data or not? have u initialize the array?@user2176687

Comment: yes, in the log i made just before assigning the cell content, it comes out as what it should

Comment: newBooksBorrowed is an array